# Why must I pass twice - isolated scope's method arguments?

Tags: angularjs

I have a markup:

```
 <div ng-controller="ProductController">
        <inventory-Product 
                on-report="showData(p.name,p.price)" 
                ng-repeat="p in products" 
                name="{{p.name}}" 
                price="{{p.price}}">
        </inventory-Product>
 </div>
```

And a directive:

```
myApp.directive("inventoryProduct", function ()
{
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope   : {
            name : "@",
            price: "@",
            onReport:"&"
        },
        template: '<div>{{name}} costs {{ price}}$ </div> \
                   <div>\
                    <button \
                       class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" \
                       ng-click="onReport({name:name,price:price})">\
                     Change name\
                   </button>\
                  </div>'

    }
})
```

*(The code is working)*

**Question:**

The  `onReport:"&"`   allows the directive to call some parentScope function and pass in its parameters.

Ok — so `onReport` is like a *delegate* which points to whatever function that was declared in the html markup :

```
on-report="showData(p.name,p.price)"
```

But If the  directive's template *already* sends the arguments in :

```
 ng-click="onReport({name:name,price:price})"
```

And the parentScope's controller function *already knows* the function  :

```
$scope.showData = function (name,price)
    {
        alert("name="+name+" price="+price)
    }
```

Then **why** do I have to mention parameters *again* in

```
on-report="showData(p.name,p.price)"  ?
```

In other words  , it seems more logical to write

```
on-report="showData"
```

So it just *points* to the function and then go with this path  :

[image]

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `ng-click="onReport()"`, and it will work fine. Or try with `on-report="showData(name, price)"`, and it should work fine too.

You use `onReport({name:name,price:price})` from the directive when you want to pass arguments (which would be called name and price respectively), from the directive itself. It's useful if the directive computes values, stored in in its own isolate scope, that must be passed to the function: the calling controller can't access these values, since they're not in its scope.

If the controller already has the values to pass to the function in its scope, and the directive should just execute that function call (as in your example), then `onReport()` is all you need.

Comment: Thank you. When you say _the calling controller can't access these values, since they're not in its scope_ - what calling controller? In other words-  what is actually happening in my sample ? ( parameters POV) , what if the controller dont have the values ?

Comment: The calling controller is ProductController. It's inside a view controlled by that controller that the directive is used. So showData() is a function exposed on the scope of that controller.

Comment: *what if the controller dont have the values ?* then you would use `on-report="showData(name, price)"`, and these two arguments would be provided by the directive, using `onReport({name:name,price:price})`.

Comment: the key of the object is the parameter name. The value is whatever you want. For example, you could use onReport({name:'hello',price: 1.99}). You need to specify the parameter names because the user of the directive could choose to do `on-report="showData(1, 2, name, foo, bar, price)`. It's free to use whatever expression it wants, and to use or not the parameters sent by the directive: name and price.

Comment: Oh now I see !!! -  I think it all boils down becuase of the same key value that I gave.The `on-report="showData(name, price)"` is actually an contract which tells the directive : _"since the controller doesn't have the values , then do your own calculation in your private controller and then send WHATEVER to  my two params which are named : name and price."_ Right ?

Comment: I think you got it. But I'd rather see it like the directive offering a feature: if you want to be notified when the name and price change, then provide a function in the on-report attribute, and the name and the price will be passed to this function under the arguments 'name' and 'price'. Just like, for example,if you want to be notified of a click on an element, you use ng-click, and the ng-click directive passes an argument named $event, that you can use if you're interested in the click event.